# startActivity using android:name

Tags: android

Manifest definition:

```
 <activity android:name="com.gannett.democratandchronicle.billstrainingcamp.PlayersActivity" />
```

WORKS:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, PlayersActivity.class));
```

DOESN'T WORK: (No activity found)

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.gannett.democratandchronicle.billstrainingcamp.PlayersActivity"));
```

Why can't I use the full android:name to startActivity? Is the string parameter expecting something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an [action](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28java.lang.String%29), not a name.  If you want to be able to launch your activity that way, add

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.gannett.democratandchronicle.billstrainingcamp.PlayersActivity" />
</intent-filter>
```

to your activity, or you can use any name you want for the action, it does not have to be the name of the class.  It does, however, have to have a namespace.